# Error on calling node api before waiting for page to load

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am  developing using Node.js and MongoDb which has a header like shown below in the image

[image]

Each of the header element calls a node.js api which does some mongoose aggregate calls and return some data and page gets render. Everything is working fine but when user click any menu it take 5-10 seconds to be loaded and in between if user clicks another or same menu button (while page is loading) some variable not defined error occurs in node api which already defined. Application working fine when users waits for page to be fully loaded before clicking other menu button.

```
app.get("/services", function(req, res) {



mongoose.connection.db.collection("dummy", function(err, collection) {

    collection.aggregate(
        [{}]
    ).toArray(function(err, site_count1) {


        mongoose.connection.db.collection("dummy", function(err, collection) {

            collection.aggregate(
                [{}]
            ).toArray(function(err, site_count2) {
                label=["scared","excitement","loved/liked","anger","unhappy","concerned","happy"]
                mongoose.connection.db.collection("dummy", function(err, collection) {

                    dataset={}
                    diet = []

                    diet = []
                    typ="Emotion"

                    dataset[typ] = {}
                    //console.log(typ)
                    collection.aggregate(
                        [
                            {}
                        ]
                    ).toArray(function(err, pro) {


                        console.log(diet)
                        dataset[typ]["label"]=(categ1) //Here error is coming dataset[typ] not defined and this is already defined above at line 28
                        dataset[typ]["x-axis"]=label.sort()




                        mongoose.connection.db.collection("dummy", function(err, collection) {


                            collection.aggregate([{}]
                            ).toArray(function(err, pro) {

                                mongoose.connection.db.collection("dummy", function(err, collection) {


                                    collection.aggregate(
                                        [{}]
                                    ).toArray(function(err, pro) {




                                        res.render("sentimentview", {
                                            dataset: JSON.stringify(sentiment)
                                        });
                                    });
                                });

                            });

                            //        if(proc==Type.length)
                            //        {

                        })

                    });

                    //        if(proc==Type.length)
                    //        {

                })
            })
        })


    })


});
});
```

Above is sample code of node call made on clicking services. Error is coming at

> dataset[typ]["label"]=(categ1)

this code if users clicks on button again without waiting for page to load.

Comment: put a condition to check if `dataset` exists or not before accessing its properties, u can add just before where you are getting the error,   like this:
`if(dataset && dataset.type){...all your things here..}`

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty but its working fine if i wait for request to finish before making another call

Comment: yeah, so in your case, `dataset` or may be `dataset.typ` or `dataset.type.label` is not exists, thats why u getting error, if you keep a condition, then it wnt throw a error, only it will do those operation if those values are there